# Cannot Install Web Grease 1.5.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webgrease

When I try to install Web Grease 1.5.1 I get this error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At L:\PROJECT_PATH\packages\WebGrease.1.5.2\tools\install.ps1:45 char:5
+     $msbuild.Xml.AddProperty("WebGreaseLibPath", $relativePackageUri.ToString(). ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the folders inside the "packages" folder in your application folder. Then try to reinstall web grease from nuget. See if that solves your issue.